# WPF отображение pdf, epub

Tags: wpf, pdf, epub

Вопрос такой WPF в каком элементе(ах) можно корректно просмотреть pdf, ebup файлы? Для просмотра pdf файлов пытался добавить Control "Adobe Pdf Reader" через создание UserControl, там проблема в последних версиях ридера `axAcroPDF1.LoadFile()` этот метод не работает да и использование Pdf ридера не желательно, `RichTextBox` выводит только текст.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF axAcroPDF1;
this.axAcroPDF1 = new AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF();
this.axAcroPDF1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
this.axAcroPDF1.Enabled = true;
this.axAcroPDF1.Name = "axAcroPDF1";
this.axAcroPDF1.OcxState = ((System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.State) 
(resources.GetObject("axAcroPDF1.OcxState")));
axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(DownloadedFullFileName);
axAcroPDF1.Visible = true;
```

или  [так](http://www.screencast.com/t/JXRhGvzvB)